# Fetch Text from UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, nsstring, nsurl

I am new to iPhone developer,

I am loading a webpage in my UIWebview,

After loading is done when user selects any text then i want to fetch that text,

here is my code snippet,

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      CGRect webFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 500.0, 500.0);
      webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
      [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
      NSString *urlAddress = @"http://stackoverflow.com/";
      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
      NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
      [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
      [self.view addSubview:webView]; 

    NSString *t= [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"];
    NSLog(@"selected text=%@",t);

}
```

but my Log shows nothing when i selects any text.

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into this [Tutorial](http://zaldzbugz.posterous.com/how-to-mark-or-get-the-highlighted-string-ins). Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"];
```